# Thresholding PSD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a positive semi-definite matrix $A$. Then we threshold it, so that we set all elements greater than or equal to $T$, to $1$, and the others to $0$.
Is it possible that the outcome matrix is no longer positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Consider $A=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&\frac12}$ with $T=1$. The result of thresholding is $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}$, which is indefinite.

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot.